# Spring Security config cyclic dependency error

Tags: spring-security, dependency-injection, jwt

I have got a working custom Spring Security Configuration, to secure certain url patterns using a JSON Web Token instead of a HTTPSession.

I order to enable [method based security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-method) in opposite to url based patterns, I need to register an AuthenticationManager, which fails due to a cyclic dependency:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: 
Factory method 'authenticationManagerBean' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: 
A dependency cycle was detected when trying to resolve the AuthenticationManager. Please ensure you have configured authentication.
```

My own dependency is to a filter which I need in order to configure it. Everything works fine, when I omit the registration of the AuthenticationManager:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private StatelessAuthenticationFilter statelessAuthenticationFilter;

    public SpringSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                ...
                // check specific paths for specific role
                .antMatchers("/...").hasRole("...")
                ...

                // all other calls must be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                // custom filter to parse JWT token previously sent to client from header and create Authentication
                .addFilterBefore(statelessAuthenticationFilter, (Class<? extends Filter>) UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                ...
    }

    // config works fine without this method, but method security needs an AuthenticationManager:
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just returning the AuthenticationManager like shown below fixed the problem:

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return authenticationManager();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the authentication manager ... like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.authenticationProvider(new MyCustomAuthProvider());
}
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. I already fixed it with my answer below, so I don't know if your approach works too.